# Locate XPath content of HTML in C#

Tags: c#, xpath, web-scraping, html-parsing

I am working in C# .net Core.

- I have HTML files
- For each file I have a XPATH which points to part of the page

Which library/nuget package can I use in C# to extract my data?

I want:

```
extractedData = xpathLib.Extract(htmlContent, xpath)
```

I do not want to use a technique which load a html browser process (like selenium driver opening chrome) since I have to extract 10 000 of webpages per day.

regards.
ps: i have seen microsoft provides xpath lib, but it targets only xml.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [HTML Agility Pack](https://html-agility-pack.net/)

This nuget works with XPATH, XDocument and LINQ. And easy to use.

Here is an example from [HTML Agility Pack](https://html-agility-pack.net/):

```
var url = "http://html-agility-pack.net/";
var web = new HtmlWeb();
var doc = web.Load(url);
var value = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td/input");
```

Comment: Yes, I did. I used for get books' detail from a page. I can't get it your second question.